# Running my NodeJS program from bash on Windows writes lots of whitespace and cursor disappears

Tags: node.js, bash

When I'm trying to run a command, bash appends a big space and the cursor disappears. I've searched for a solution and I haven't found any. Can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that *bash* is writing all that whitespace, as opposed to it being written by the node.js program you're running? The cursor isn't displayed by bash itself, it's displayed by your terminal; if the node program emits sequences that tell the terminal to stop displaying a cursor, well, there you are.

Comment: If you want your cursor back, run `reset` to put the TTY back to its normal settings.

Comment: BTW, I suspect strongly that this wouldn't happen on a native UNIX system, *or* if you had a MinGW-compiled version of `node`; it likely has a fair bit to do with how MinGW's terminal management differs with that of native Windows apps.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the response, I already typed reset but the problem's still the same :/ and I tried to reistall git bash and node and alsoe nothing ..

Comment: Yes, there's no reason to believe reinstalling the same version of either component would help; it doesn't fix the problem that one of them is Windows-native and the other one is not. In a *real* terminal emulator (with a correctly set `TERM`), `reset` would work; but you're in a much more... let's say, Windows-y... environment.

Comment: Honestly, my approach would be to *not use Windows* (or, if using Windows, to not use a UNIX portability layer others than Microsoft's officially supported syscall-level one). I realize that doesn't help you much.